# Java - Output blocks of n consecutive lines in opposite order

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i want to store every n consecutive lines into 1 block and output each block in reverse order from which they were read, but in each block the order in which they were read.

for example if a block is 2 consecutive lines, and my input is:

```
dog

cat

rabbit

bear
```

then two blocks would be formed, and my output would be:

```
rabbit

bear

dog

cat
```

i have tried using an ArrayList and counter to keep track of the number of lines, but i am not getting the correct output.

```
  public static void reverseBlock(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   
        
        for(int counter=0; counter<2; counter++){
        
            for (String line = r.readLine();line != null; line = r.readLine()){
                
            list.add(line);
                    
             }
     }
        
        Collections.reverse(list);
        for(String text:list){
        
            w.println(text);
        }
        list.clear();
        
    }
```

Comment: I gotta ask the standard question: What have you tried?  You've gotta give us some idea of where you're at, otherwise we're not answering a question, we're just writing a program for you.  Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Say you had a file called `input.txt` with the following contents:

```
dog
cat
rabbit
bear
```

Maybe you could consider utilizing a **[Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)**:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
  static final String INPUT_FILE_PATH = "input.txt";
  static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 2;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Deque<Deque<String>> reversedBlocks = new ArrayDeque<>();
    reversedBlocks.addFirst(new ArrayDeque<>());
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(INPUT_FILE_PATH))) {
      stream.forEach(word -> {
        if (reversedBlocks.getFirst().size() == BLOCK_SIZE) {
          reversedBlocks.addFirst(new ArrayDeque<>());
        }
        reversedBlocks.getFirst().addLast(word);
      });
    }
    reversedBlocks.forEach(words -> words.forEach(System.out::println));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
rabbit
bear
dog
cat
```